# How to add and insert enum text values into Vue project HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, interpolation

I have an enum called MaritalStatus:

```
enum MaritalStatus {
  Single,
  Heartbroken,
  Married,
}
```

And an array of objects which incorporates that enum
(This is a typescript project btw):

```
const contacts: Contact[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tony",
    age: 18,
    maritalStatus: MaritalStatus.Heartbroken,
    dateOfBirth: new Date(2006, 1, 2),
    occupation: "Software Engineer",
  },
  {etc.}
]
```

Here is the only part of my HTML that matters:

```
<div
  v-for="contact in contacts"
  :key="contact.id"
>
  <span class="my-2">{{ contact.maritalStatus }}</span>
</div>
```

When this displays, I get a list of names, with numbers 0-2 displaying below them. Obviously what I want to display is the text "Single", "Married", or "Heartbroken".

How do I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `typescript` will automatically assign auto-incrementing numerical values to your enum keys under the hood. You have 2 options:

Use value assignment:

```
enum MaritalStatus {
    Single = "Single",
    Heartbroken = "Heartbroken".
    Married = "Married"
}
```

Or access the value using an index accessor:

```
martialStatus: MaritalStatus[MaritalStatus.Heartbroken]
```

Comment: Yes! Value assignment was what I was missing. Thank you very much